# Си++ QT creator

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу приложение на QT 5.12, мне нужно по кнопке выдать порядковое свободное число для пользователя, например в exel файле есть строки заполненные данными, например строки 1-3 заняты, пользователь заходит в приложение и хочет добавить информацию, для этого он нажимает на кнопку и ему присваивается номер 4.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй перебирать строки и сравнивать значения, если строка пустая то дай ей значения

Answer (score 0):

Хранить кол-во записей в вашей "базе" в какой-то переменной. По закрытию приложения записывать переменную в отдельный файл со служебной информацией, который будет читаться каждый раз при запуске.

Вопрос никак не относится к QT  и с++ ,это общепринятая практика на любом яп.
[Вам стоит ознакомиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)